# spring boot fail to register component and return 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm pretty new with spring boot reactive api and i couldn't understand why my controller was registered.

project tree

```
├─src
│  ├─main
│  │  ├─java
│  │  │  ├─com
│  │  │  │  └─example
│  │  │  │      └─demo
│  │  │  └─hello
│  │  │      │  Application.java
│  │  │      ├─reactive
│  │  │      │  └─api
│  │  │      │          GreetingHandler.java
│  │  │      │          GreetingRouter.java
│  │  │      │`
│  │  │      └─sub
│  │  │          └─api
│  │  │                  GreetingController2.java
│
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("hello.reactive.api")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

GreetingRouter.java

```
@Configuration
public class GreetingRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(GreetingHandler greetingHandler) {

    return RouterFunctions
        .route(RequestPredicates.GET("/hello").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)), greetingHandler::hello);
}
```

when I run application and tried http://localhost:8080/hello, always return error page with this:

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

please any comment to help this question..!

Comment: You need to show exactly how you're making your request. Your route registration explicitly requires `Accept: text/plain`. (Also note that `@SpringBootApplication` already contains `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.)

Answer (score 0):

In your pom use this dependencies -> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.1.3.RELEASE
and in your GreetingRouter, use like this:

```
  @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class GreetingRouter {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public ResponseEntuity<ServerResponse> route(GreetingHandler greetingHandler) {

    RouterFunctions router = new RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/hello").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)), greetingHandler::hello);
    return new ResponseEntity<ServerResponse>(router, HttpResponse.OK);
}
```